# Problemas com append() e html() do JQuery

Tags: php, jquery

Já vi um outro exemplo aqui no fórum mas não me ajudou muito pela quantidade de itens inseridos na `div`.

```
$carrinho = '<div class="carrinhoMais">
               <a href="carrinho.php">CARRINHO</a>
               R$ <label class="totalCarrinho">'.$phpUtil->formataMoeda($semiTotal).'</label>
             </div>';

echo '<script>$(".carrinho").html('.$carrinho.');</script>';
```

Não estou conseguindo popular a `div`.

Já tentei

```
echo '<script>$(".carrinho").append('.$carrinho.');</script>';
```

Também não deu.

Acho que é pela quantidade de html.

Dá o seguinte erro.

```
index.php:214 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
```

Linha 214

```
<script>$(".carrinho").html(
      <div class="carrinhoMais">
       <a href="carrinho.php">CARRINHO</a>
       R$ <label class="totalCarrinho">12,00</label>
     </div>
);</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Tente isso:

```
echo "<script>$('.carrinho').html('".$carrinho."');</script>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Consegui.

Obrigado!

```
<?php 
if(empty($_SESSION["carrinho"])) {    

    echo '<script>$(".carrinho").html("CARRINHO VAZIO")</script>';

 } else { 

    $semiTotal = 0.00;

    foreach ($_SESSION["carrinho"] as $carrinhoP) {

         $semiTotal += $carrinhoP["precoUnitario"] * $carrinhoP["quantidade"];
    }

    $carrinho = "<div class='carrinhoMais'><a href='carrinho.php'>CARRINHO</a>R$ <label class='totalCarrinho'>".$phpUtil->formataMoeda($semiTotal)."</label></div>";

    echo '<script>$(".carrinho").append("'.$carrinho.'");</script>';

}
?>
```

Outro problema é que o JS não aceita quebra de linhas da forma abaixo:

```
$carrinho = "
          <div class='carrinhoMais'>
            <a href='carrinho.php'>CARRINHO</a>
            R$ <label class='totalCarrinho'>".$phpUtil->formataMoeda($semiTotal)."</label>
          </div>";
```

Precisa ser tudo junto

```
$carrinho = "<div class='carrinhoMais'><a href='carrinho.php'>CARRINHO</a>R$ <label class='totalCarrinho'>".$phpUtil->formataMoeda($semiTotal)."</label>/div>";
```

Comment: Justamente, o problema estava nas falta das aspas ao redor do html que você estava tentando inserir.